# Specifying session / cookies info while unit testing Struts 2 Actions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, struts2

It seems that while unit testing Struts 2 using `SessionAware` actions, the session is not set on the action. Is there a way to specify session info manually during the tests, before the action or any of its interceptors are executed? (The interceptors must also receive the same session info which I specify.)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19056281/1700321.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the session and session values using the Action proxy before executing the actual test case , following is the code snippet that demonstrate the functionality.

```
 ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy(<actionName>);
 Map<String, Object> session = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 session.put(....
 actionContext = proxy.getInvocation().getInvocationContext();
 actionContext.setSession(session);
```

Comment: This will hook up with the SessionAware interceptor and the session will get placed into the action as normal?

Comment: yes this will work, we are using this in our on-going project

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Do you know a way to do the same with cookies?

Comment: i think it is stright forward create cookie using java code and set that in response/request object. Cookie cookie = new Cookie("url","<website>");
  cookie.setMaxAge(60);  ,
  response.addCookie(cookie);//request.setCookie(cookie)?? FYI: i didnt tried this code !